# Will any memory card reader with USB interface work on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, memory-card

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04. I need to add/remove files from a "microSD" memory card. Before buying a memory card reader, I want to know if **any** memory card reader with a USB interface will work on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I've never had any problems with the several that I've tried.

Answer (score 1):

99.999% of all USB card readers present themselves as USB Mass Storage Devices.  This is a standard interface which Ubuntu handles well.

It would be a very rare one that wouldn't work with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**: Almost all USB card readers are considered USB Mass Storage Devices.  As this device class includes flash drives as well, there is no reason for any USB card reader to not work on Ubuntu.